# How to evaluate parameter inside Freemarker macro?

Tags: freemarker

Suppose we have a simple Freemarker macro:

```
<#macro myMacro expr>

    <#local x=1>
      ${expr}
    </#local>

    <#local x=2>
      ${expr}
    </#local>

</macro>
```

---

<@myMacro "A"/> gives:

A
A

---

I need something like
<@myMacro "A${x}"/>  should give:

A1
A2

but it doesn't work as ${x} interpolated before passing into macro.
This doesn't work even if I use raw string r"A${x}" as a parameter.

I tried to play with ?eval but there is no result yet(((

Is it possible to do what I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to evaluate an expression here, or a template snippet? An expression is like `1 + 2` or `"A${x}"` (note the quotation marks; it's a string literal), which when you pass it in will look like `<@myMacro "1 + 2" />` and `<@myMacro r'"A${x}"' />`; the last is quite awkward. A template snippet is like `<#list 1..x as i>${i}</#list>` or `A${x}` (note the lack of quotation marks), which is more powerful and looks nicer inside a string. From what I'm seeing, you probably want to evaluate a template snippet, so it should be:

```
<#macro myMacro snippet>
  <#-- Pre-parse it for speed -->
  <#local snippet = snippet?interpret>

  <#local x = 1>
  <@snippet />

  <#local x = 2>
  <@snippet />
</#macro>
```

and then you can use it as:

```
<@myMacro r"A${x}" />
```

or even:

```
<@myMacro r"<ul><#list 1..x as i><li>${i}</li></#list><ul>" />
```

Anyway, the whole thing is a bit strange usage of FreeMarker, and if you rely very heavily on `?interpret` or `?eval` (like you do hundreds of it per HTTP request), you will possibly find it slow. Slow with Java standards, that is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your method with "?interpret" is acceptable to me!
My usage of freemarker is rather specific, I use it for source code generation, so the performance of "?interpret" is not so important.