# Use Freemarker macro call within string parameter of another macro

Tags: macros, freemarker

I have a macro A that formats some text
`<#macro A text>...${text}...</#macro>`
and another macro that has a parameter accepting text
`<#macro B x>Another ${x} text</#macro>`

I'd like to call B with the x paramter to be some text formatted by A, s.th. like
`<@B x="<@A text='abc'/>" />` returns `Another <@A text='abc'/>`

Is this possible somehow?

I tried the `?interpret` as [suggested here by ddekany](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8369688/1480587) - 
`<@B x="<@A text='abc'/>"?interpret />` but this fails with the error:

> Expecting a string, date or number here, Expression .... is
>   instead a freemarker.core.Interpret$TemplateProcessorModel

It seems that a macro call in FreeMarker is something different than a function call in other languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macro calls aren't expressions, and hence can't be used inside expression (like a parameter value). Macros are called for their side effects, which is typically printing to the output, and have no return value. Functions (see `#function`) are called for their return values, and so function calls are expressions. So maybe you need functions, not a macros in this case.

But if you absolutely have to use the output of a macro call in an expression (or of any arbitrary template fragment), then you have to capture the output via `<#assign someVar>...</#assign>` or `<#local someVar>...</#local>`. (Beware with `#escape`. If you re-print the captured output with `${...}`, it will be escaped again, so you will need `#noescape`.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I forgot about functions ... anyway FreeMarker is definitively a really cool language ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround using assign:

`<#assign a><@A text="abc"/></#assign>
<@B text=a/>`

Anyway, it would be interesting to know if this is possible somehow.